# Class extension in Prefix.pch no longer works with xCode 4.2

Tags: objective-c

I included a header in my prefix.pch file as so:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif 

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Constants.h"
#endif
```

And in the included header is a class extensions:

```
@interface UIColor (MyApp)

+(UIColor *) myColor;
+(UIColor *) navColor;

@end

@implementation UIColor (MyApp)

+(UIColor *) myColor { return [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.3 blue:0.7 alpha:1.0]; }
+(UIColor *) navColor { return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.1 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0]; }

@end
```

Which I then called in other files as such:

```
[self.theTable setSeparatorColor:[UIColor myColor]];
```

But since upgrading to xCode 4.2 / iOS 5 it now causes a crash, saying `"Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT".` at the above line.

This happens whenever I try and reference the color regardless of which file and what context. I did not have this problem when working on iOS 4.

Is there a better was to extend a class in a way that is available to all files, or to fix the above error?

Many thanks,

Tim

Comment: And where is the implementation of `[UIColor plColor]`?

Comment: Sorry Lukman, had modified the code to make it generic, but forgot to rename the last one! have edited the post now. If only the fix had been that simple :) (or it might still be, who knows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declarations should be in a header:

```
@interface UIColor (MyApp)

+(UIColor *) myColor;
+(UIColor *) navColor;

@end
```

and your definitions should be in your .m:

```
@implementation UIColor (MyApp)

+(UIColor *) myColor { return [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.3 blue:0.7 alpha:1.0]; }
+(UIColor *) navColor { return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.1 blue:0.2 alpha:1.0]; }

@end
```

that may not necessarily be the reason for your SIGABRT, but your `@implementation` block should only ever be visible to one translation (surprised it did not give a link error, unless i misunderstood your question).

Is there any more context to *why* the program crashed?

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to. My only sticking point was why would it work in 4.* and not 5.0?

Comment: @NJones idk! as i said, i would have expected a link error. a link error is what happened in the past, and i didn't even know multiple definitions of the same objc method was properly formed at some point (i still suspect it is not). perhaps it is simply differences in clang?

Comment: Rather simple solution! Can't believe I didn't think of this. Just saw an example of a generic header online somewhere which included both in one file, and it worked, so I didn't think twice about it when using it. Then when it broke on the new update, it didn't occur to be that it was fundamentally wrong! Works a charm again. Thanks guys.